# Jquery .on doesn't seem to work with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Why following doesn't work:

```
$(function()
{
    $('#settings').on('click', '.link', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('okay');
    });
});
```

...when just prepending `body` to selector makes it work?

```
$(function()
{
    $('body #settings').on('click', '.link', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('okay');
    });
});
```

This code is executed by `$.getScript(...)` call *just after* `#settings` is inserted into DOM by `$('body').append(...)`.
I want to use `.on()` since `.link`s can be created dynamically and I don't want to rebind events all over the place.

Browsers affected: Firefox, Chrome, possibly more
JQuery version: 1.11.0

Comment: Fixed closing brackets. jsFiddle is a problem since it'd need to make mentioned $.getScript call which I feel is mandatory to reproduce the case.

Comment: Can you post more code? Can it be you are using AJAX and the `$('body').append(...)` is happening later than you expect?

Comment: I will provide more code ASAP; the basic idea is that `$.getScript()` call occurs inside AJAX success handler, right after appending the content from AJAX call.

Comment: What do you get if you do `console.log($('#settings'));` just before `getScript`?

Comment: And, I must ask, you have just one `#settings`, right? ( i can remove this comment to not polute when you answer)

Comment: You're brilliant, turns out I had two elements with the same ID. :facepalm: I was logging just `$('#settings').length` and it was 1 so I thoguht it's ok - it couldn't actually show the extra element. Please provide an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's [must be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18453687/2256325).

In this case it seems you might have more than one element with the same ID, thus the odd behaviour you are getting.

Comment: Thanks again; gotta use less IDs from now on.

Comment: Happy to help! Well, they are handy some times. You can also use data-attributes, they are also handy. Cheers